# Including a keyfile in pymongo's MongoClient()

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo

I used to connect to a mongo server with:

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host,int(port))
```

However, we recently installed individual keyfile security in accessing the database.  I have [consulted documentation here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient), and [in other examples](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mongo/python-driver/pymongo/mongo_client.py), and it looks like the right way to include that should be:

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host,int(port), ssl=True, ssl_keyfile="/.ssh/mykeyfile")
```

However, trying either the ssl_keyfile or ssl_certificate flags both return

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Unknown option ssl_certfile
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Unknown option ssl_keyfile
```

How can I add this parameter to connect with keyfile authentication?  I am puzzled that this item that is specified clearly in the documentation is throwing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of pymongo are you running?

The SSL options were added in 2.5, and works here (I'm using 2.6.3). Referring to the doc you linked:

> Changed in version 2.5: Added additional ssl options